# How to encode a new line in BibTex?

Tags: bibtex

Say I have a paper with this title: (notice the newline character)

```
nom nom\nburrito
```

And I need to export it in BibTex format:

```
@article{NomBurrito,
    title = {{nom nom???burrito}}
}                    ^^^
                     How do I encode a newline in BibTex?
```

How do I manage the newline character? With `{\\}`? Which seems to be how you would do it in LaTeX but I'm not sure whether that is true for BibTex too.

Comment: Usually when papers have a multi-line title, for example a title and a subtitle, or a title consisting of two sentences, then you just write them as one line in the bibliography. If that looks strange because of lack of punctuation then you can add a comma, period, or colon between the two lines. If the newline is actually essential for interpreting the title then it would be useful to know the name of the paper to offer more specific remarks.

Comment: @Marijn Thank you for your answer. I don't have a specific example unfortunately (although I _could_ try to get one if that really helps). Assuming it is essential what would you recommend though? (I'm building a reference manager so I need to cover some edge cases)

Comment: Both `\\ ` and `\par` probably work, although the new line may be indented. However, this should not be necessary except for very unusual circumstances (as mentioned above). Note that putting titles in double brackets could be problematic as it interferes with formatting conventions that a bibliography style is trying to apply.